# Difference Between SetPixel(Color.black) and not Set Pixel with any Color

Tags: c#, .net, image, colors, bitmap

When you create a new Bitmap and use the SetPixel() function and set the parameter Black color the result is same as when you don't set any color for specified pixel and save the bitmap in Jpeg format.
After i save my image and i read Jpeg image file later how should i know the pixel has real Black color or is not set?

Comment: What makes you believe that there *is* a difference?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have two pictures and get the difference between images and save my file in Jpeg format.know if i merge my first picture and difference picture, i should get the second picture,but i can't detect which pixels are not set and which pixels are real black

Comment: that didn't answer the question, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PNG. It is compressed image format. Its main benefits over JPEG are that it's lossless and supports transparency. On simple images that only have a few colors, I have experienced even smaller image sizes using PNG.

If you for some reason just have to use JPEG, I would use some specific color to express "no pixel". If you want to use black (0, 0, 0) as this color key, you have to use different color for true black pixels. This could be for example be 0x000001 (0, 0, 1). Eyes are unable to different it from true black but a computer program can. So if there is 0x000000 (0, 0, 0) colored pixels in image just replace it with 0x000001 (0, 0, 1). Be careful though, JPEG's lossy compression can cause problems when using this technique. Using higher quality should solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks,your idea is the best.

Answer (score 1):

“Not set” and “black” are the same in a JPEG. By default, it’s black. In a format with transparency, like 32-bit PNG, is where you’re going to be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Yes , you right but i should save my file with Jpeg format for compression.

Comment: @samangholami: PNG has compression too. It’s a moot point if JPEG doesn’t work for your purposes.

Comment: PNG is Lossless , and the produced result size isn't suitable for my work

Comment: @samangholami: From the sounds of it, neither is JPEG. Does this need to be pixel-perfect? You can set one transparency key, but since JPEG is lossy, transparency probably won’t be preserved in all cases. If your images are palletted, you might try GIF.

Comment: I think your idea about transparency key is good.but i don't know which color can i use for transparency key?

Comment: @samangholami: I don’t know either, you’ve been pretty vague about the whole thing so far. You mentioned up above that the produced PNG is 50KB, though; that’s tiny, and if it’s not suitable, we probably need a lot more detail about what you’re using this for.

Comment: @samangholami If you use JPG, any color you choose may get "corrupted" by the lossy compression process of JPG. As a user I would certainly not accept a JPG output to represent a difference image.

Comment: @minitech i using it for creating a video file.the images are my frames

Answer (score 1):

JPEG files don't support transparency so every pixel has *some* color - whether you explicitly set it or not. That's why it doesn't matter that you didnt' set a certain pixel's color - when you save the bitmap as JPEG, all pixels will be saved with some color. The ones you didn't set will be saved with the default which is black.

When you use an image format, such as PNG, that supports transparency, there's another 'color' available (which is the default): the transparent color. This is the color that's used by default for pixels that are not explicitly set.

Note that the transparent color is not really a separate color: each pixel has a transparency byte (assuming the pixel format is ARGB) and by default the transparency byte is set to 255 (full transparency) for each pixel. So the transparency of each pixel can be controlled independently of others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so you said i can't detect real black pixel and empty pixel in jpeg format?i need it for the compression...do you have any idea?

Comment: There's no "empty pixel" in JPEG. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I have two pictures,i want save some pixles of pic1 that the color of them different from pic2.and i save the result as a jpeg image.after that, i want create picture two,with pic1 and the result pic.so i should know which pixel is black and which pixel doesn't set.if the pixle isn't set ,so the pic1 pixel is like pic2 pixel and if the pixel set, i should replace pixel with result pic.

Comment: @samangholami I'm sorry, you'll have to reword what you wrote. I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to say. Are you trying to save an image that represents the differences between two input images?

Comment: I'm sorry for that ... Yes.

Comment: @samangholami Int that case I'd recommend using PNG as your output format. JPEG is a lossy image format so your output wouldn't be reresentative of the difference of the inputs even if the black pixels wouldn't be a problem (and they are, you cannot resolve it within the constraints of JPEG). The compression in PNG is almost as good as JPEG and it's not lossy so pixels won't get blurred based on compression level.

Comment: the result file with jpeg format and highest quality (100L) has 8kb and with png format has 50kb size.and with this quality when i merge pictures i can produce the correct result

Comment: @samangholami It doesn't matter. You either accept the limitation of JPG or you use a different image format. PNG is by far the best fit for this unless you come up with a new data format to describe your output. You need to decide if size is more important than the ability to tell if a pixel is "empty".

Comment: Small error: alpha isn't _transparency_, it's _opacity_. The default is 0, which is fully transparent.